# Fonction de paie dans "L'équipe paie"

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Voici un extrait d'un email professionnel :

> Les congés de Noël 2020 et les derniers congés sur 2020 doivent être
> posés avant le 15/11/2020. Les compteurs CP2020 doivent être soldés au
> 31/12/2020.
>
> D'avance, merci.
>
> **L'équipe paie.**

Quelle est la fonction de *paie* dans la dernière phrase ?

Comment: On écrit plus souvent ce substantif **paie** mais, peut être pour éviter l'homophonie avec *paix*, on le prononce à peu près toujours \pεj\ qui correspond plus à son autre orthographe, en déclin, **paye** (rime avec soleil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les mots "équipe paie" font office de signature du mail, ainsi je peux en déduire qu'il s'agit du nom de l'équipe :

L'équipe qui s'occupe des **paies** des collaborateurs.

Cela peut faire référence à un groupe de personne au sein du pôle comptabilité et/ou ressources humaines de l'entreprise. Cela dépend de l'organisation et du jargon utilisé par l'entreprise.

On aurait pu également avoir "La compta" ou "L'équipe RH" etc.